# Python extract words from a txt file

Tags: python-2.7

Is it possible to search for a series of words & extract the next word. For example in a txt file search for the word 'Test' & then return the word directly after it?

```
Test.txt
This is a test to test the function of the python code in the test environ_ment
```

I'm looking to get the results:-

```
to, the, environ_ment
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
import re

txt = "This is a test to test the function of the python code in the test environ_ment"
print re.findall("test\s+(\S+)", txt) # ['to', 'the', 'environ_ment']
```

The regular expression matches with "test" when it is followed by white space (`\s+`) and a series of non-white space characters `\S+`. The latter matches the words you are looking for and is put in a capture group (with parentheses) in order to return that part of the matches.